# How do Oppermann's and Bertrand's conjectures deal with prime gaps?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

From this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap), it states

> There are gaps between primes that are arbitrarily large ...

**QUESTION**

Probably a silly question, but how do these conjectures pick a starting $n$? What happens if there exists a prime gap large enough to encompass both start and end bounds, so that whatever $n$ is chosen, these conjectures fail since they're contained in a prime free gap?

For example, construct a prime gap

$\large m!+2, m!+3, m!+4, …, m!+2(m!+2)+1$

Bertrand's states there is always at least one prime $p$ such that

$n<p<2n$

Now, let $n$ have this starting value

$n=m!+2$

The prime gap now looks like this

$\large n, m!+3, m!+4, …, m!+2n+1$

which defines $2n$ consecutive composite numbers.

Thus, we have a range from $n$ to $2n$ but does not contain any prime $p$?

**Oppermann's Conjecture**

At least a prime between $n^2$ and $n^2+n$

**Bertrand's Theorem**

At least a prime between $n$ and $2n$

Comment: This is not clear.  What is the question?  Large gaps between primes occur for very big numbers...is that what you are asking?  Bertrand's postulate is a known theorem, by the way.  Opperman might be false, for all anyone knows, though numerical evidence looks good.

Comment: Suppose there is a large fictitious prime gap between $100$ and $300$. Suppose we apply Bertrands with $n=100$. Then it says that there's a prime $p$ between $100$ and $200$. However, since $n=100$ was chosen as a starting number, it falls within the large prime gap, so the conjecture isn't true for that case?

Comment: As I say, Bertrand's postulate is a theorem, so the situation you describe can not occur.  As to the open problems, well...that's the whole point.  The various conjectures claim that the intervals they describe don't lie entirely inside prime gaps but of course the unproven conjectures might be false.  That's the problem with conjectures.  Until someone proves or disproves them, we don't know whether or not they are true.

Comment: Perhaps it clarifies things to look at the "cheap" proofs that there are arbitrarily long prime gaps.  Those mostly go by the Chinese Remainder Theorem....if we want a gap of length $≥k$ we look at the first $k$ primes, $p_1, \cdots, p_k$ and choose an integer $N_k\equiv -i\pmod {p_i}$.  But $N_k$ is a residue $\pmod {p_1\times \cdots p_k}$  and the product of the first $k$ primes is very very big.  Certainly it is enormously greater than $k$ or $k^2$.  Thus, as far as this argument goes, we expect the big prime gaps to occur "very far out"...

Comment: ...but, of course, these vague arguments don't prove much.  Maybe there are long prime gaps among much smaller numbers.  After all, finding one long prime gap doesn't preclude the existence of others.  But, on balance, I'd say the intuition should be that long prime gaps occur sparsely.

Comment: The span referenced in both Oppermann and Bertrand as you have stated them is $n$, so if there were only one prime in such a span, the size of a prime-free gap would be greater than $\frac{n}{2}$ which can become arbitrarily large, consonant with the statement cited from the article. To be picky, if there were some small number $k$ primes in the span, there would be a gap greater than $\frac{n}{k+1}$, which also might become arbitrarily large, supposing $k$ did not vary with $n$.

Comment: That arbitary large prime gaps occurs cannot even be used to prove that there is a prime $p$ with $n<p<2n$ for every $n>1$. But the prime number theorem can prove it. The best known general upper bound for a prime gap after any sufficient large prime $p$ is $p^{0.525}$ , but there are probably much better bounds. $\ln^2(p)$ for example has not yet been refuted. This would be much better than what we need to prove Oppermann.